# Magento : How Can We Mail a File From Frontend

Tags: magento-1.7, module, email, frontend, file-upload

In my website, I have an option to choose a file.

I want file to be mailed to a particular email-id.

### Screenshot of the file upload screen

[image: upload screen]

I want to have a button which should mail selected file to a particular email-id.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

The code which is used to set attchment with mail.

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

$translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
$transactionalEmail = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
$filepath = COMPLETE_PATH_UPLOADED_FILE; 
if(file_exists($filepath)
{
$transactionalEmail->getMail()
                ->createAttachment(
        file_get_contents($filepath),
        Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
        Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
        Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
        basename($uploadfilename)
    );
}
$transactionalEmail->sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, OTHER_VARIABLES, $storeId);
$translate->setTranslateInline(true);
```

Comment: I am not able to save the uploaded file, hence, not able to mail the same.

Comment: @RajatAgarwal have done any code to save the selected file in particular place when button is clicked? In no, then you need to do that thing first.